# django dynamic modelform won't validate

Tags: python, django, dynamic, django-forms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Validating a form with overloaded *init*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12081628/validating-a-form-with-overloaded-init)

I've spent the entire afternoon trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong here, and I know it's going to be something face-palmingly stupid.  When the user fills out a form, the location selection box depends on the country of the user and lists different cities accordingly.

Model & Modelform

```
class Cars(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    location = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
    created = models.DateTimeField(default=utc_time)

class CarsForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, country, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CarsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['location'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Cities.objects.filter(country=country))

    class Meta:
        model = Cars
        exclude = ('owner', 'created',)
```

View

```
def new_car(request):
    if request.method == u'POST' and request.is_ajax():
        form = CarsForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
                      etc...
```

Following advice from stackoverflow, I edited the modelform **init** to allow the country  variable to be passed.  The form creation and html displays fine and everything works great, only now the form won't validate.

UPDATE:
Ok, it looks like I (meaning 'YOU') got it working.  Several things were ugly, and once fixed it works ok:

- the location field type was changed to foreignkey, correcting the
  data mismatch issue
- the init was revised to accept country as a kwarg
- the form validation now passes the variable as a kwarg
  CarsForm(request.POST, country=country)

SUCCESS!  In under an hour.  Thanks so much everyone!!

Comment: Yes it's the same underlying problem.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but `ModelChoiceField` sets it's value from the queryset in it's `to_python()` method. Wouldn't that be a direct contradiction to the field type defined in the model for `location`? `location` isn't a foreign key, it's a `PositiveIntegerField`, which seems to be why there would be a validation error.

Comment: @Brandon that's a secondary problem. No data is bound to the form so `is_valid` bails early without running any actual validation.

Comment: Yes, I agree because the `country` isn't getting handed to the form. No one had pointed out the data type mismatch yet, which should throw a validation error as well, correct?

Comment: `country` is given as `request.POST`. `data` (the original first arg to the form `__init__`) is not given so the form isn't bound and you won't see any validation errors.

Comment: (god you guys are fast) You're right about the form not being bound.  It doesn't even get to the data type issue, which I overlooked as being part of this mess.

Comment: Ah, I couldn't tell where the `country` was coming from. I assumed it was supposed to be passed to the form when the class was instantiated

Comment: Yeah, country is being passed when the form is instantiated, and it's getting the queryset and displaying fine.  It's everything else that's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either this is the solution, or your copy-and-pasting has problems `;)`

You've correctly defined the over-ridden `__init__` method, but you're not actually passing a `country` parameter; doing so would look like this:

```
form = CarsForm(country, request.POST)
```

This means that `request.POST` always gets stored in `country` and never  passed on to the parent class's `__init__` method.

If the form gets no data, `is_valid()` will always return `False`.

A side-note: where does `SkillForm` come from? Should be `CarsForm`.

Comment: Edit screwup --SkillForm should be CarsForm!  I'll fix it to avoid unnecessary confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Your change makes `country` the first argument but you are passing the `POST` data as the first argument. `form = CarsForm(request.POST)`